# Incorrect uv map

Tags: uv

I have this 3d model, and I used box projection on it, but then this happened. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!  Could you please elaborate on what it's doing that you don't want?  I can't really tell what is wrong.

Comment: Without knowing your intentions it's hard to know what's "incorrect" about this...

Comment: UV is mapped incorrectly, you can see the weird seam in the middle.